# "way round" vs. "way around"

Tags: word-usage

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/nbnRm_3_QKU?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=563)

> It doesn’t matter which way **round** the sounds are.
> You can link /d/ to /t/ or /t/ to /d/.

To my ear, it sounds like

> It doesn’t matter which way **around** the sounds are ...

I guess I understand the meaning of it as a whole sentence, which is, both orders `a to b` and `b to a` are acceptable and understandable.

I am just not familiar with the usage "way round" or "way around"

Ngram Viewer shows both are common, the actual use in first pages don't convey ideas similar to the one above.

[image]

Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster "around"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around)

4 a: in rotation or succession
4 c: in order ***the other way around***

So, it refers here to the order of succession of the letters (which is first or second), as you understood. I think that "way around" amounts to an idiom, and you can use it in these ways, and maybe others:
the right way around
the wrong way around
the other way around
which way around

In the US, the word is "around", but "round" is used in the same sense in England.